# Popup alert showing prematurely?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, alerts

I'm working on a submission form that includes a few required fields, and I have a segment of code that allows a popup menu to appear once you hit the "submit" button, and from there once you hit "ok" on the alert you're redirected to the home page. Here's the code I have for the popup alert.

```
<div id="popup">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction(){
                alert("Thank you! \nYour sumbission has been 
                accepted and you will receive a conformation email shortly! \n
                You will now be taken to the Home page.");}
        </script> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</div>
```

And this is the beginning of the code for redirecting you to the homepage.

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="text"> 
        <h1>Your Information</h1>
            <form id="contact_form" action="home.html" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="home.html" />
```

(Note: I clipped the above segment of code because the following information is only the form input boxes)

And this works like you would imagine, the alert popping up once you hit the submit button. However my question is that I have a few required fields on my form, and if the fields are not filled out and you hit "submit", the popup alert appears, and once you hit "ok" on the alert, because you have yet to fill out these fields it takes you back to the form and a little box saying "this field is required" appears.

This is in the wrong order. I want the alert box for the required fields to show *before* the popup alert for the confirmation of form submission, so that if you have required fields and you hit submit it will tell you to fill out the required fields before the message appears thanking you for submitting.

This may be a simple fix of placement or adding a little code but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it or finding an example that could help me.

If you know what to do I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

**Edit:** This is the javascript file for the validation code.

```
window.onload = setForm;

function setForm() {
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
      if (this.checkValidity()) alert("No invalid data detected. Will 
      retain data for further testing.");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the validation code?  How does it get called?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Validation()
{
vak k = true;

 k = function 1 validates field 1 AND returns true or False based On Validation
 k = function 2 validates field 2 AND  returns true or False based On Validation
 k = function 3 validates field 3 AND returns true or False based On Validation
 return k;
 //At The End Of This Function You Need To Get "TRUE" To Truly Submit.
}

On Submit :

If(Validation() == true)
{
then Only Submit
}

Write Back If It Dosen't Works...
```

Comment: This is still producing the same result as my aforementioned code  . . . Maybe I'm not implementing it correctly?

Comment: 1:Are U receiving true From Validation() function On Clicking Submit button.TRUE indicates That There Is No Required Data Field On Form.

Comment: You Can Debugg Javascript In Firebug To See What Is Hapenning...On Clicking Submit Button...do reply fast if not hapenning

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="popup">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="required" id="required"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="click" value="Submit">
               <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
  <script>
    var click = document.getElementById("click");
click.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var required = document.getElementById("required").value;
  if (required===null || required==="") {
    alert("Please make sure all required field are completed");
  }
  else  {
    alert("Thank you! \nYour sumbission has been accepted and you will receive a conformation email shortly! \nYou will now be taken to the Home page.");
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com", 5000);
  }
});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://jsbin.com/wuxahape/1/

Comment: I tried this and it displayed the same message whether or not the required information was filled or not; even if all necessary input boxes were filled it displayed the "please make sure all required fields are completed" message before redirecting to the home page.

Comment: have you click the link it work for me, you may need to clean you browser data [click hear](http://jsbin.com/wuxahape/1)